# Custom add-in field does not inherit background colour of panel it is placed on

Tags: c#

I have a custom drop down menu which I have placed on a blue coloured panel. The drop down menu does not inherit the blue color of the panel, instead a white square appears around it. I have tried setting the background to transparent using SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true); but this makes the whole of the drop menu disappear. I have also tried setting the backcolor and forecolor to the systemcolor but that doesn't fix it either. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to support a solid background only or you want the drop down menu to be truely transparent, i.e. support background images/gradients?

Comment: Hi, I just want the background color to match - not the drop down menu to be truly transparent.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself properly there...I want the actual drop down menu to keep to it's color I have set, but I want the area around this (the square which is currently white) to be transparent and inherit the color of the panel I have placed it on. Thanks.